# setOnSucceeded is not called

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I'm trying to implement JavaFX Task with setOnSucceeded listener.

```
class GetDailySalesTask extends Task<ObservableList<VBox>>
    {

        @Override
        protected ObservableList<VBox> call() throws Exception
        {
            TabContentInfrastructure content = new TabContentInfrastructure();
            return FXCollections.observableArrayList(content.initTestTabContentData());
        }
    }
```

And I call the Java Class here:

```
VBox vb = new VBox();

Task<ObservableList<VBox>> task = new GetDailySalesTask();

Region veil = new Region();
veil.setStyle("-fx-background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4)");
veil.setPrefSize(240, 160);
ProgressIndicator p = new ProgressIndicator();
p.setMaxSize(140, 140);

//p.progressProperty().bind(service.progressProperty());
veil.visibleProperty().bind(task.runningProperty());
p.visibleProperty().bind(task.runningProperty());
//vb.visibleProperty().bind(service.runningProperty().not());
//tableView.itemsProperty().bind(service.valueProperty());

StackPane stack = new StackPane();

System.out.println("service.valueProperty() = " + task.valueProperty());

task.setOnSucceeded(new EventHandler<WorkerStateEvent>()
{
    @Override
    public void handle(WorkerStateEvent t){

        System.out.print("Yes**********" + t.getSource().getValue());
        stack.getChildren().clear();
        t.getSource().getValue();
        stack.getChildren().addAll(task.getValue().get(0));


    }
});



task.setOnFailed(new EventHandler<WorkerStateEvent>()
{
    @Override
    public void handle(WorkerStateEvent t){

        System.out.print("Entered setOnFailed**********" + t.getSource().getValue());



    }
});



stack.getChildren().addAll(vb, veil, p);

tabdata.setContent(stack);
new Thread(task).start();
```

And for some reason setOnSucceeded is not called. Can you help me to fix this issue?

P.S

```
public class TabContentInfrastructure
{

    public VBox initTestTabContentData() throws InterruptedException
    {

        Thread.sleep(5000);
        final VBox vbox = new VBox(0);
        FlowPane flow = new FlowPane();
        ........................
        vbox.getChildren().addAll(flow, screenController);
        return vbox;    
    }
}
```

Comment: Register a setOnFailed (or use a try-catch in your call) to see if an Exception is being thrown.

Comment: I updated the code. When I run the code I always get `Entered setOnFailed**********`. How I can debug it further?

Comment: I only get `Entered setOnFailed**********null`. Where I have to place try/catch block?

Comment: Can you post the code of TabContentInfrastructure?

Comment: Post updated - see the bottom. Basically all content of the Java method consists of a Java methods with SQL queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

U must clear that,

Javafx Application thread and worker thread are totally different.

you must to read first this tutorial. [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/threads/jfxpub-threads.htm)